# Log4j2 - Configure RolloverStrategy to delete old log folder

Tags: log4j2

When the log files are archived, the log files are placed in a folder named after the year and month. Now i deleted the old log inside the log folder, now how can i delete this empty folder。

Comment: How did you delete the old logs?

Comment: Delete the old log file, if its parent folder becomes empty, delete the parent folder too

Comment: That's telling what you did, not how you did it. You wrote "Now i deleted the old log inside the log folder". Are you making a program do that? If so, how?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.